# Having issues connecting to a server with VS Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, web-hosting, data-connections

I just purchased a hosting account from Go Daddy with a SQL Server database and I'm trying to connect to it with VS Pro.  I've tried everything I can think of, and called Go Daddy as well.  I have SQL server 2008 on my machine, but Go Daddy has SQL Server 2005 - Which I'm sure will bring about even more issues...

In my server explorer, I clicked the icon to add a new server. The diologue appeared and asked to enter the server name.  I have a different username and password than my windows ones, so I clicked the link to enter my creds.  After that I used the server name (or as Go Daddy called it - the Data Source) which is in the format -mydatabasename.db.7numbers.hostedresource.com

I keep getting the errorr "Make Sure Machine Name and Path are Valid".

I've also tried using the "connect to database" icon in the server explorer and tried all combinations of everything I can think of.  Has anyone experienced this who may have some ideas for me to try?

This is just one of those days where I'm SO frustrated just but can't give up...please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can laugh at myself for this one - when I initially set up the database I checked a box to make it read only - not allowing access to make changes.  I created a new one and this time I allow access and can put a string in my web config file that hooks up to it.  Sometimes it's the little things that get us...

Answer (score 1):

Your hosted server likely does not allow remote connections in this manner for security reasons.  Otherwise, some hacker would own your box instead of you.  You need to use Go Daddy's tools for managing your environment instead of connecting directly from your dev box.

Comment: hmmm...I wonder why they provide me with the server name for a SQL connection.

I suppose I can just  rebuild the darn thing from their tool.  Thanks!